# bcp - dump via xp_cmdshell vs. sp_oaMethod Security

Tags: sql-server, security, xp-cmdshell

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and I try to dump a table via bcp (with a scheduled Job). First of all I implemented it with xp_cmdshell, but I've heard, that this should be avoided due to security reasons.

So my question: What's about sp_oaMethod? Should it be used? If not, why not? And could you suggest other possibilities?

Comment: I recently had reliability problems with using `sp_oa...` and writing files (FSO), and moved to xp_cmdshell with no issues.  I never found the cause.  Not an answer, but may help you decide if you're on the fence.

Comment: thank you for your response ... I'm not allowed to use xp_cmdshell anymore - It's only due to the security issues, not because of functionality

Comment: Why would you use the sp_OA% procedures when you could use CLR support instead? It's much better and will give you a lot more flexibility. Although if you just want to run bcp.exe then you can simply put it in a batch file and call it from the SQL Agent job, or even call bcp.exe directly.

Comment: xp_cmdshell can be used safely,  but it should be disabled if there is a risk of sql injection associated with that ms-sql account.  Simply not using it doesn't help secure system,  that is just silly.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution than `xp_cmdshell` is to use a SQL agent job step of type "CmdExec" or 
"Powershell".

[CmdExec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190264.aspx) would be my preference for a one-liner call to `BCP.exe`. Sysadmin credentials are needed to create the job step.

[Powershell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280490.aspx) is your answer if you need to perform any additional tasks, for example zipping the extracted file and copying it to a network share.